# PHP Connection Error, defining the connection correctly?

Tags: php

So I've looked at responses from other threads, but I cannot find my error. 
Here is my php file:

```
<?php

  define('con', 'con');  
  define('db_name','db_name');
  define('mysql_user','mysql_user');
  define('mysql_pass','mysql_pass');
  define('server_name','server_name');

  $db_name = "commentsdb";
  $mysql_user = "root";
  $mysql_pass = "root";
  $server_name = "localhost";
  $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);

  if(!con)
  {
    echo "Connection Error...".mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else {
    echo "<h3>Database connection Success...<h3>";
  }
```

?>

Here is my error:
( ! )

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): in C:\wamp\www\webapp\init.php on line 11
>       Call Stack
>       # Time    Memory  Function    Location
>       1 0.0006  134536  {main}( )   ..\init.php:0
>       2 0.0007  135112  mysqli_connect ( )  ..\init.php:11

I've exhausted all options. Thanks!

Comment: Is that successful when you use other connect tool by these credentails? or you miss the port of you database?

Comment: Can I ask why you're defining connection details, then instantiating variables as well?

Comment: Why you defined constants?

Answer (score 0):

Please use any of the mysql client to test this..connect via mysql workbench or phpmyadmin using the same credentails

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
//Create Databases
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Your Database";
$password = "Your Password";
$dbname = "Your Database";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

$sql = "INSERT INTO...";

/*Multiple query example:
$sql = "INSERT INTO...";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO...";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO...";
*/

//If you have multiple query use: multi_query()
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Succesfully Created!";
    } else {
        echo "<pre>Error in Database! Error: " . $conn->error . "</pre>";
    }
    $conn->close();
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me

Please Check the values of your variables are correct or not ($db_name | $mysql_pass )

```
$db_name = "commentsdb";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_pass = "root";          
$server_name = "localhost";
```

Answer (score 0):

via OpenShift

rhc app create test php-5.4 mysql-5.5

```
1 <?php
  2     define('con', 'con');
  3     define('db_name','db_name');
  4     define('mysql_user','mysql_user');
  5     define('mysql_pass','mysql_pass');
  6     define('server_name','server_name');
  7
  8     $db_name = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST');
  9     $mysql_user = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME');
 10     $mysql_pass = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD');
 11     $server_name = getenv('OPENSHISHT_GEAR_NAME');
 12     $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);
 13
 14     if(!con)
 15     {
 16       echo "Connection Error...".mysqli_connect_error();
 17     }
 18     else {
 19       echo "<h3>Database connection Success...<h3>";
 20     }
 21   ?>
```

**Database connection Success...**

Your MySQL server or  user are misconfigured.

PaaS's such Openshift and many others use properly configured servers, you do not need to think about configuration  servers. Easy plans usually free of charge.